# Fewest digit 8s and +-*/() to get 1000?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, puzzle

Here it is with eight 8s:
$$888+88+8+8+8 = 1000$$
Here it is with seven 8s:
$$8\times8\times(8+8)-8-8-8 = 1000$$

Is it possible with less?

Comment: Is exponentiation allowed?? i.e. $8^8$?

Comment: If exponentiation, $\sqrt{}$ and $!$ are allowed, which is reasonable in my opinion, you can do better: $$\sqrt{\frac{8^8}{8+8}}-(\sqrt{8+8})!=1000$$ which takes only 6 eights (and looks pretty damn cool :D).

Comment: You could use use $(\sqrt{8+8})$! instead of 8+8+8 in mine but yes it's cool.

Comment: For more ideas here see [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/puzzles/eight-eights-solution.html).

Comment: @DietrichBurde thanks those are all eight 8s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only $3$ essentially different solutions with $7$ digits "$8$":

$$
(8+8)\cdot 8 \cdot 8 - 8 - 8 - 8 = 1000;
$$

$$
8\cdot (8+8\cdot(8+8))-88 = 1000; 
$$

$$
(8+8)\cdot \left(8\cdot8 -\frac{8}{8}\right)-8 = 1000. 
$$

To find them, one can build:

1 - list of possible numbers, which can be obtained from $1$ digit "$8$": $\{8\}$;

2 - list of possible numbers, which can be obtained from $2$ digits "$8$": $\{0,1,16,64,88\}$;

etc.
(Each list is derived from all previous ones).

And $6$th list will be without number $1000$, so there are no solutions with $6$ (or less) digits "$8$". 
If only $+,-,*,/$ and $()$ are allowed.

Comment: Yeah I found the first one and included in the question, the second is really nice - but this doesn't answer the question: is it possible with six or even less?

Comment: @chx, I updated the answer ...